# Which color for a "Pay now" button?

Tags: buttons, color, call-to-action, payment

I know there is no such thing as *one* good color that can be universally accepted, but I've been told **orange** is the "right color" for the payment button, and it is notable to see how both Paypal and Amazon use this color (but Google doesn't):

[image: amazon paypal google checkout buttons comparison]

So I thought it would be interesting to know if **there is some research on which is the best color for a payment button, and why is it better?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reds, yellows and oranges are spotted swifter by the human eye, and multivariant testing typically confirms that call-to-action buttons get the most clicks when they're orange - and by a significant margin. Reds and yellow both do well; greens often come out poorest. Yellow possibly fares a little worse on the web because humans have a harder time resolving it against a white background.

However, if your application already has very strong visual semantics, where a particular colour is strongly tied to 'positive' actions, you may find it still garners attention even when it isn't orange or red. If your branding doesn't use reds or yellows, you lose some visual consistency which can help convince users that yours is a professional and trustworthy site. However, there are other ways to garner enough user trust, and A/B testing may prove that yellow buttons offer too big and advantage to turn down.

Comment: thanks, I like your insights. Do you have any studies that can shed some science/statistics for my reading pleasure?

Answer (score 5):

The best color will depend on your site colors. You need the button to be visible, therefore a contrasting color might be a good choice.

I would suggest that you pick some colors, and perform a simple a/b testing on the site.

Answer (score 3):

I think the payment button in an e-commerce shop should reflect the main colors in the branding. 
ex. If the logo is purple with white then the payments/purchase button should be along those lines. This way if the user "likes" the brand then he'll "like" the button too...

But yes, red/orange creates more emotion than other colors in certain type of individuals.

**Red:** Energy, Increases heart rate, creates urgency, often seen in clearance sales

**Orange:** Agressive, Creates a strong Call To Action, subscribe, buy or sell.

**More details in this infographic here :**

http://blog.kissmetrics.com/color-psychology/

Answer (score 0):

I Think Red and Orange is the best color for call-to-action buttons. The user will see it prominent. And its out aim to . User always try to click the highlighted things. So button should be Orange and Red.

Answer (score 0):

I would not mind clicking a payment button if it is green. It looks least offensive and most friendly to me. But I agree this might be my personal experience and overall design of the site and color scheme should have a larger role to play here.