# Color Scheme for an Older Demographic

Tags: website-design, buttons, web, visual-design

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this color scheme too distracting for a senior demographic?
2. Do you think the blue puts enough emphasis on the "buy now" button? Or does is not stand out enough from the play button and peace of mind tab?

[image]

Alternatively;

[image: Edited]

Comment: And I have looked around at other call to action related questions: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15639/which-color-for-a-pay-now-button

Comment: I'm not sure about the colour scheme, and I don't know what scale this is at, but the text seems quite small for an older user. I think the main thing to focus on re the colour would be the contrast, as this deteriorates with age -- the white text on green background might be a problem.

Comment: @Brendon I made it purple.  It's a little more readable now. I wish the orange fit better, oh well..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eye sight decreses with age, so if your target audience is elderly, focus on (1) white-space, (2) contrast rather than color and (3) larger font size and (4) buttons that look like buttons.

[image]